# How to avoid duplicate rows when using simple joins

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables.

Table **Alpha**:

```
ID     NAME
____   _____
```

Table **Beta**:

```
NAME    GOALS
_____  _______
```

Table **Charlie**:

```
NAME   SCHOOL 
_____ _________
```

I want a table

```
ID    NAME    GOALS    SCHOOL 
______________________________
```

Note:

ID's are not unique. so for each ID there may be many names. The issue right now is I get MANY MANY duplicate rows when i use inner joins or left joins. Do help (SQL Newbie)

Thank you :))

Comment: please update your question to show the query that is not working correctly.

Comment: did you try inner join based on name? is your name column primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Name is your foreign key, so if there are two of the same name in Beta, or Charlie, it's going to duplicate the Alpha rows.

What you need to decide is how you'll aggregate the values from the other tables.
You'll probably want the sum of goals for each name, but school, you'll have to pick one. Otherwise you'll have duplicate rows for each school per name.

So, if alpha is

```
1 John
2 Sue
```

And Charlie is

```
John UHT
John MIT
Sue MIT
```

You'll end up with

```
1 John UHT
1 John MIT
2 Sue  MIT
```

If Beta has

```
John 4
John 5
```

It gets worse. Now John is going to show up 4 times.

So, you'll need to apply aggregate methods. Then do

```
... Group By Name
```